# ¿ Como resolver la compatibilidad de los navegadores web para que mi pagina se visualicen todos los estilos en todos los navegadores?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

lo que pasa es que tengo mi pagina vista con bootstrap, CSS, HTML5 y jquery. Lo que pasa es que al visualizar mi pagina en google chrome se visualiza perfecto pero la veo em IE y los estilos no se ven de la manera en que se ven en crhome, tampoco algunas funciones de operación  de jquery no funcionan tampoco he intentado varias cosas como resetear los estilos y otras cosas mas, pero no he tenido éxito, Ayudaaa..

Comment: 1 Chrome 66 33.27%
2 Safari 11 11.60%
3 Chrome 65 3.98%
4 UC 11 3.52%
5 IE 11 2.95%

Comment: Hola, podrían ser mas específicos, es que no comprendo nada.

Comment: Ya casi nadie usa IE, mira este link: https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: Lo se, pero el sistema que estamos haciendo pues eso a los usuarios no puedo decirselos ellos la abren en el navegador que quieran incluso safari presenta esos mismos errores por eso deseo saber como resolver el tema. he intentado varias cosas y ni una ha dado resultado.

Comment: La cuestión es que ese no es un problema específico, con cientos y hasta miles de problemas pequeños de compatibilidad que no tienen una respuesta mágica o automática que te podamos dar aquí.

Comment: Si hay algo que ya deberíamos tener claro los programadores es que así sea ínfimo el número de usuarios que utilicen un navegador debemos hacer lo posible (y según el tipo de cliente que toque, lo imposible...) por tener la mayor compatibilidad posible. Si, sabemos que internet explorer es un desastre, un fallo total en lo que a compatibilidad y rendimiento se refiere pero sigue siendo un navegador utilizado y ya eso es motivo suficiente para (así sea haciendo magia) intentar lograr compatibilidad de nuestra aplicación con este navegador. Ojo no estoy a favor de internet explorer.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow! Tal cual como dice @SaulAxelMartinezOrtiz trata por favor de especificar mejor que problemas de compatibilidad estás teniendo (margenes, altura, anchura, barras de desplazamiento, posicionamiento relativo o absoluto). Sería de gran ayuda si colocas el código para que podamos depurarlo y ayudarte mejor. Un saludo

Comment: Si no te lo han puesto como requisito imprescindible, te recomiendo que pongas un mensaje al abrir la página web como que IE no está soportado y los navegadores recomendados. IE ya no lo soporta ni Microsoft, así que no vamos a ser nosotros los que lo hagamos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas a tener en cuenta para optimizar la compatibilidad, por ejemplo, IE no es capaz de hacer un margin entre un elemento y el documento, es decir, si el primer div de tu pagina tiene un margin-top: 30px; IE no sabe trabajar eso y se mostrará pegado a arriba.

Normalmente para un caso así lo que se hacia (y se sigue haciendo cuando se trabaja con IE) es poner contenedores vacios para ocupar espacios.

Esto es solo un ejemplo que a mi me ocurrió, pero cosas así hay cientas.

Tu pon dudas mas concretas y si está en mi mano te ayudo.